# What is the reputation limit upto which an user has the "new contributor" tag under their name?

Tags: support, new-users, reputation, new-contributors

Today I saw a question which had one answer. The answerer/user/contributor has 816 reputation points. However, the **New Contributor** is still visible under his name.

[image: Ted Pal]

How is this working? I mean some people start of their journey with 1 reputation point and make their way up. The **New Contributor** logo disappears after the user has posted a minimum number of questions or answers (which I think is two, please correct me if I am wrong). Some people start with 101 reputation points because ***SE trusts you on different sites in the network***. The main point, the wordings of **New Contributor** disappears after a few days. Then how can a person with this many reputation points be a "New contributor"? What is the reputation limit for this to disappear?

PS: I have no personal rivalry of any sorts with the person mentioned above in the picture. I simply want to know the reputation limit till which the **New Contributor** tag shows up below a person's name. Please inform in case this is a glitch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reputation limit; all that matters is that the user's first post is less than a week old. From [Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/295232)

> Folks will see an indicator when they go to interact with new contributors (visible for a week following their first post) letting them know that the person is new.

FWIW, the main and meta site are counted separately. A user who has been active for years on the main site may still have a 'New contributor' indicator here on meta, shortly after posting their first post here.